# Adding html <a> tag in php

Tags: php, html

Is there any way to add an html `<a>` code in a php script like here:

```
<div id="flashDiv" align="center" style="position:absolute; top:20%; left:30%; z-index:51;">
<?php if ($OS == Windows): ?>
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/file.exe">
    <img src="http://localhost/flower.png"></img>
</a>
</div>
<?php else: ?>
nothing
```

Comment: Yes, but in your example the endif is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use correct syntax :p

```
<div id="flashDiv" align="center" style="position:absolute; top:20%; left:30%; z-index:51;">
<?php if ($OS == "Windows"): ?>
<a target="_blank" href="http://localhost/file.exe">
    <img src="http://localhost/flower.png">
</a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: There's no `</img>` Will you please correct it. `:)`